# Why clear method not exist on @testing-library/user-event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, user-event

I am working on a CMS project and I just came across an issue. `_userEvent.default.clear is not a function`.

```js
import user from '@testing-library/user-event'

test('can edit label', async () => {
    createArticleMock()
    await renderRootAndInitStore(rightNowTeasers, globalInitialState)

    const index = 1
    const input = screen.getByDisplayValue(labels[index])
    const newLabel = 'VÄRLDEN'
    user.clear(input)
    user.type(input, newLabel)

    expect(await screen.findByDisplayValue(newLabel))
    user.click(screen.getByTestId('settings-form-save'))
    await screen.findByText(newLabel)
})
```

When I visit `@testing-library/user-event`, I see those lines

```js
// Definitions by: Wu Haotian <https://github.com/whtsky>
export interface IUserOptions {
    allAtOnce?: boolean;
    delay?: number;
}

export interface ITabUserOptions {
    shift?: boolean;
    focusTrap?: Document | Element;
}

export type TargetElement = Element | Window;

declare const userEvent: {
    click: (element: TargetElement) => void;
    dblClick: (element: TargetElement) => void;
    selectOptions: (element: TargetElement, values: string | string[]) => void;
    type: (
        element: TargetElement,
        text: string,
        userOpts?: IUserOptions
    ) => Promise<void>;
    tab: (userOpts?: ITabUserOptions) => void;
};

export default userEvent;
```

As the file shows, there is no `clear()` method on `userEvent`. But the documentation points out to `clear()` method.

Doc => [Doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/user-event)

This is first time I use this library. Anyone knows what the issue is?

Comment: It looks like those types are missing *two* of the documented methods - `toggleSelectOptions` isn't there either. They're both there in the latest version (https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/blob/master/typings/index.d.ts), maybe you need to update or wait for a release.

Comment: `npm i -D @testing-library/user-event` and `npm audit fix` solved the issue. Thanks jonrsharpe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Have to update the @testing-library/user-event to the latest version.
Then that error will be resolved. You Can find the latest version over here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/user-event

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the other answers/comments, the best solution is to upgrade `@testing-library/user-event`. However, if you are stuck on an old version for some reason, you can use this workaround.

Instead of this:

```js
user.clear(input);
```

try this:

```js
user.type(input, "", { allAtOnce: true });
```